# Polymer 1.6: Element not being styled

Tags: css, polymer

I have a Polymer element I've been trying to style for several hours now. I've looked at several videos, documentation, just about everything says including an ID and just styling it as normal should work, but it just doesn't.

I have code here: http://codepen.io/nanobird_/pen/pEWWqW/

This is my dom module code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.5.6/polymer.min.js"></script>

<dom-module id="kink">
    <template strip-whitespace>
        <style>
            :host {
                display: inline-flex;
                border: 1px solid black;

                z-index: 0;
                line-height: 1;

                height: 40px;
                width: 16em;
                margin: 2px 8px;
            }

            #kink-color {
                width: 4px;
                background-color: aquamarine;
            }

            #kink-text {
                background-color: green;
                margin-left: 4px;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
            }
        </style>

        <div id="kink-color"></div>
        <div id="kink-text"><content></content></div>
    </template>



    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'kink',

            properties: {
                pref: String
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>

<kink pref="yes">Kink</kink>
```

The custom element should look similar to how the div group looks just below it- a box with a little swatch of color to the left.

What on earth am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Custom elements need a `-` in the name. The polymer element doesn't seem to be initialized at all. Check the console log for errors.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Needless to say, I feel like an idiot now. Is that even documented anywhere? And could you make a post to accept that as the answer?

Comment: It's easy to miss if you don't explicitly look for it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement

> tag-name
>   The name of the custom element. The name must contain a dash (-), for example my-tag.

See also https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements

> By specification, the custom element's name must contain a dash (-).